# How to load symbols for 'arrow.dll' when using RDotNet?

Tags: c#, r, apache-arrow

I'm currently using RDotNet to try and read a parquet file into json like this:

```
StartupParameter rinit = new StartupParameter();
rinit.Quiet = true;
rinit.RHome = "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.3";
rinit.Interactive = true;
REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();

string json = String.Empty;

using (var engine = REngine.GetInstance("C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.3/bin/i386/R.dll", true, rinit))
{
    json = engine.Evaluate("json <- rjson::toJSON(arrow::read_parquet('C:/temp/myFile'))").AsCharacter()[0];
}
```

However, most of the time (yes, it's worked a few times) I get the error:

> "Symbol file not loaded. No symbol file loaded for arrow.dll"

How can I make sure it consistently loads the symbols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I hadn't installed the arrow package through R.